# Array values to keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am parsing some XML to JSON and then serving this on http://floating-gorge-9520.herokuapp.com/currencies.

I want to display the data so the values for `currency` are the keys and the values for `rate` then become the values for the new currency data.

For example:

```
USD: 1
GBP: 0.5
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using two currencies for simplicity:

```
require 'json'
a = [{"currency"=>"USD", "rate"=>"1.3707"},
     {"currency"=>"JPY", "rate"=>"140.50"}]
Hash[a.map { |h| [h['currency'],h['rate'].to_f] }]

# => {"USD"=>1.3707, "JPY"=>140.5}
```

Just append a `.to_json` on the last statement to get the JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://ideone.com/Ggm79R) out

```
require 'json'
a = {}
json = '[{"currency":"USD","rate":"1.3707"},{"currency":"JPY","rate":"140.50"},{"currency":"BGN","rate":"1.9558"},{"currency":"CZK","rate":"27.368"},{"currency":"DKK","rate":"7.4625"},{"currency":"GBP","rate":"0.82183"},{"currency":"HUF","rate":"311.89"},{"currency":"LTL","rate":"3.4528"},{"currency":"PLN","rate":"4.1661"},{"currency":"RON","rate":"4.5222"},{"currency":"SEK","rate":"8.9953"},{"currency":"CHF","rate":"1.2195"},{"currency":"NOK","rate":"8.3670"},{"currency":"HRK","rate":"7.6685"},{"currency":"RUB","rate":"49.0415"},{"currency":"TRY","rate":"3.0097"},{"currency":"AUD","rate":"1.5283"},{"currency":"BRL","rate":"3.2577"},{"currency":"CAD","rate":"1.5304"},{"currency":"CNY","rate":"8.3495"},{"currency":"HKD","rate":"10.6313"},{"currency":"IDR","rate":"16097.50"},{"currency":"ILS","rate":"4.8062"},{"currency":"INR","rate":"85.1580"},{"currency":"KRW","rate":"1469.53"},{"currency":"MXN","rate":"18.2348"},{"currency":"MYR","rate":"4.5158"},{"currency":"NZD","rate":"1.6558"},{"currency":"PHP","rate":"61.092"},{"currency":"SGD","rate":"1.7376"},{"currency":"THB","rate":"44.603"},{"currency":"ZAR","rate":"15.1355"}]';
JSON.parse(json).each { |x| a[x['currency']] = x['rate'] }
print a
```

Comment: This just outputs the same as before?

Comment: Fixed. Check the same link out.